# Unable to connect to SQL Server database, Membership

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, connection-string

I've been using membership in vs2010 and never had a problem using it. Now i'm using VS2012 and am currently having trouble. In my Web Site Administration Tool, i get the error message "Unable to connect to SQL Server database." I have run the regsql file. I'm using mssql 2012 not the express version and working on a local project

> 

```
<add name="XXXDbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=Local-PC;Initial Catalog=XXXDb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleManager">
      <providers>
        <add name="SqlRoleManager"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
             connectionStringName="MyConnectionString"
             applicationName="MyApplication" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>


Just had to insert to rolemanager
```